# ActiveAdmin batch action form with entries from multiple classes as input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, action, activeadmin

Following the [batch actions guide](https://activeadmin.info/9-batch-actions.html) from activeadmin, one can create a form of different types. What I want is, that the form have entries of different model classes.

I have three classes: `Shop`, `RecordingShop` and `DistributionChain`. A `DistributionChain` can have one or more `Shop`s or `RecordingShop`s but can also have none of them.

On the `Scores` index table, I want to show an export batch action and recognize which class the form entry belongs to (either `Shop`, `RecordingShop` or `DistributionChain`)

Is it possible to do something like:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Score, as: 'Delivery' do
  ...
  batch_action :export, form: {shops: (DistributionChain.all + Shop.not_distribution_chain).collect{ |e| [e.name, e.id, e.class.name]} } do |ids, inputs|
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

so that the class would be a third parameter in the nested array, after the element name and id, and include it in the `inputs` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I found a way through declaring variables in the admin resource code itself.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Score, as: 'Delivery' do
  ...
  EXPORT_INPUTS = DistributionChain.all + Shop.not_distribution_chain
  EXPORT_INPUTS_DATA = EXPORT_INPUTS.collect.with_index{ |e, i| [e.name, i] }
  ...
  batch_action :export, form: {shops: EXPORT_INPUTS_DATA } do |ids, inputs|
    element = EXPORT_INPUTS[inputs['shops'].to_i]
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

`EXPORT_INPUTS` contains the actual set of elements from multiple classes.

`EXPORT_INPUTS_DATA` is the variable (array) to use in the form and has the name and the index of the elements in the array. The chosen index can be retrieved later as `inputs['shops']` and `EXPORT_INPUTS[inputs['shops'].to_i]` corresponds exactly to the element we want.

**NB**: `EXPORT_INPUTS_DATA` should be defined outside the action. If you write

```
batch_action :export, form: {shops: EXPORT_INPUTS.collect.with_index{ |e, i| [e.name, i] } }
```

directly, `inputs['shops']` will only be equal to the id of the element in its respective class, which does not tell us anything.